# Is it best to use a comma following an inline address?

Tags: commas

Is it proper to include a comma at the very end of an inline place address? Also, in case it is relevant, the sentence is the title of an article.

For example:

> Examples of cross-gene fertilization within a sample from Bogota, Colombia 2009-2011.

or

> Examples of cross-gene fertilization within a sample from Bogota, Colombia, 2009-2011.

Comment: There's no universally accepted single authority dictating punctuation, so 'proper' is a nebulous term. Colombia 2009-2011 looks a little like a postcode or telephone numbers, so I think the transition from locative to temporal descriptor is a big enough step to merit a compartmentalising comma.

Comment: I'd go with parenthesis and a comma after them: *... within a sample from Bogota (Colombia), 2009-2011* but I may not be right.

Also notice that the country is Col**o**mbia, Col**u**mbia is a state of the USA.

Comment: Columbia is not a state, it is a federal district—the Distict of Columbia.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited to correct the typo.